# Problema al generar la media de un array

Tags: php

Tengo un problema al generar la media de un array ya que no me lo muestra en pantalla o no estoy haciendo algo bien.

El siguiente código muestra un formulario que al escribir '1' y enviar se imprime una lista de alumnos con sus notas, las notas se generan aleatoriamente en las funciones 'notaDificultadBaja()' y 'notaDificultadMedia()' y estas notas se guardan en el array $datos['notas'].

La última funcion llamada 'calculoNotasMedia()' la que esta con comentarios es la que tendría que generar las notas medias pero no me imprime nada por pantalla y en otros arrays si que me funciona.

```
<?php session_start();?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="simuladorExamenes.php" method= "get">
        Opción: <input type = "text" name ="opcion">
        <input type = "submit">
    </form>

    <?php

        if($_GET['opcion'] == 1){

            imprimeListaAlumnosNotas();
        }


        if(!existenDatosEnSesion()){

            inicializaDatos();
        }

        function existenDatosEnSesion(){
            return $_SESSION['datos'] != NULL;
        }

        function inicializaDatos(){

            $persona1= [
                'nombre' => 'persona1',
                'notas' => []
            ];

            $persona2= [
                'nombre' => 'persona2',
                'notas' => []
            ];

            $persona3= [
                'nombre' => 'persona3',
                'notas' => []
            ];

            $datos=[$persona1, $persona2, $persona3];
            $_SESSION['datos'] = $datos;
        }

        function notaDificultadBaja(){

            $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

            foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {

                $datos[$key]['notas'] = random_int(5 * 100 , 10 * 100) / 100;
            }

            echo "<td>",$datos[$key]['notas'],"</td>";
        }

        function notaDificultadMedia(){

            $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

            foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {

                $datos[$key]['notas'] = random_int(0 * 100, 10 * 100) / 100;
            }

            echo "<td>",$datos[$key]['notas'],"</td>";
        }

        function imprimeListaAlumnosNotas(){

            $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

            echo "<div class='Encabezado'>";
            echo "<h2>Lista de Alumnos y notas </h2>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
            echo "<th>E0</th>";
            echo "<th>E1</th>";
            echo "<th>Media</th>";
            echo "</tr>";


            foreach ( $datos as $alumno ) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>",$alumno['nombre']," ","</td>";

                    notaDificultadBaja();

                    notaDificultadMedia();

                    //calculoNotasMedia($alumno['notas']);

                echo "</tr>";
            }


            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<b>Notas Medias</b>";

            echo "<td/>";
            echo "<tr/>";

            echo "</table>";
        }


        /*function calculoNotasMedia($pArrayNotas) {

            $sumaNotas = 0;
            $numNotas = 0;
                    foreach ( $pArrayNotas as $unaNota ) {
                        $numNotas++;
                        $sumaNotas += $unaNota;
            }
            return $sumaNotas/$numNotas;
        }*/

    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Si todo funcionase bien quería que me imprimiese esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

> el problema es que concatenabas con coma `,`  y no con punto `.`!
>   adicional imprimias solo 1 resultado aunque tenias 3 porque no
>   imprimias dentro del bucle si no fuera.

```
<?php 

    if($_GET['opcion'] == 1){
        if(!existenDatosEnSesion()){

            inicializaDatos(10);
        }

        imprimeListaAlumnosNotas();
    }




    function existenDatosEnSesion(){
        return $_SESSION['datos'] != NULL;
    }


    //$n es el numero de datos que deseas generar
    function inicializaDatos($n){

        for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
            $datos[] = ['nombre' => "persona{$i}",'notas' => [] ];
        }

        $_SESSION['datos'] = $datos;
    }

    function notaDificultadBaja(){

        $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

        foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
            $datos[$key]['notas'] = random_int(5 * 100 , 10 * 100) / 100;
        }
        echo "<td>".$datos[$key]['notas']."</td>";

    }

    function notaDificultadMedia(){

        $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

        foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
            $datos[$key]['notas'] = random_int(0 * 100, 10 * 100) / 100; 
        }
        echo "<td>".$datos[$key]['notas']."</td>";
    }

    function imprimeListaAlumnosNotas(){

        $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

        echo "<div class='Encabezado'>";
        echo "<h2>Lista de Alumnos y notas </h2>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
        echo "<th>E0</th>";
        echo "<th>E1</th>";
        echo "<th>Media</th>";
        echo "</tr>";


        foreach ( $datos as $alumno ) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$alumno['nombre']." "."</td>";

                notaDificultadBaja();

                notaDificultadMedia();

                //calculoNotasMedia($alumno['notas']);

            echo "</tr>";
        }


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<b>Notas Medias</b>";

        echo "<td/>";
        echo "<tr/>";

        echo "</table>";
    }


    /*function calculoNotasMedia($pArrayNotas) {

        $sumaNotas = 0;
        $numNotas = 0;
                foreach ( $pArrayNotas as $unaNota ) {
                    $numNotas++;
                    $sumaNotas += $unaNota;
        }
        return $sumaNotas/$numNotas;
    }*/

?>
```